# Python - a single for loop, calculate the following the max, min and avg number of words per line in to_analyze

Tags: python, python-2.7

Need help! New to Python and have been stuck for days (hence why I am posting here, last resort!)

I need to find the maximum, minimum (the longest and shortest line based on word count) and average number of words per line (that goes into to_analyze string)

My problem is, I am able to only get the number of words per line but it's not accurate because it just prints the number of words per line and not on which line has the maximum amount of words and minimum amount of words.

This is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""Task 03"""

import re
from decimal import *

def lexicographics(to_analyze):
"""


"""
lines=0
num_of_words=0
max_words=0
min_words=0
mostWordsInLine=0

for line in to_analyze.split('\n'):
    lines +=1
    words=line.split()
    if len(words) > mostWordsInLine and len(words) != None:
        mostWordsInLine = len(words)
        num_of_words=len(words)
        max_words=max_words+len(words)
        print num_of_words
print "Decimal({:.1f})".format(Decimal(max_words) / Decimal(lines))
```

Current output:

```
>>> import task_03
>>> task_03.lexicographics('''Don't stop believing,
Hold on to that feeling.''')
3
5
Decimal(4.0)
```

As you can see ^ - I get the correct number of words but it counts the number of words for any line, not what I need.

The output should be this:

```
>>> import task_03
>>> task_03.lexicographics('''Don't stop believing,
Hold on to that feeling.''')
(5, 3, Decimal(4.0))
```

And if I want to have it also measure lines from another file

```
>>> import task_03
>>> import data
>>> task_03.lexicographics(data.SHAKESPEARE)
(12, 5, Decimal('8.14'))
```

Any help/hints are greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you are new to Python I would recommend to install 3.X. Python 2 is not getting any support 2020 and beyond.

Comment: Thank you! But this is for my Python class, and the professor only wants us to use Python 2.7x - I've tried asking for help from classmates and my professor but no response! However after this class, I will definitely do that! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To tell you that this could be all in one simple `def`:

```
from decimal import Decimal
def f(s):
    lines=list(map(lambda x: len(x.split()),s.splitlines()))
    return (max(lines),min(lines),Decimal(sum(lines))/Decimal(len(lines)))
```

Then:

```
print(f("Don't stop believing,\nHold on to that feeling."))
```

Is:

```
(5, 3, Decimal('4'))
```